# Count() on ManytoMany field while filtering a queryset?

Tags: django

I have a challenge class where people can vote for it.  Now for each vote that is cast for the user, the user shall receive 5 points.

I have solved it with a for loop.

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='speaker')
    voters  = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, , null=True, blank=True)    

score = 0
challenges = Challenge.objects.filter(speaker=user)
    for challenge in challenges:
        score = score + challenge.voters.count() * 5
```

But I wonder if I could somehow do that during filtering the queryset right away and achieve a higher performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) the Challenge objects with voter counts:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Challenge.objects.filter(speaker=user).annotate(voter_count=Count('voters'))
for challenge in challenges:
    score = score + challenge.voter_count * 5
```

Or you could aggregate the entire voter count:

```
score = (Challenge.objects
            .filter(speaker=user)
            .aggregate(vc=Count('voters'))
        )['vc'] * 5
```

Comment: +1 I like the second option. Looks clean. If the speed is great too, thats really impressive :)